# Detecting a shake device event with react-native-sensors?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, sensors, shake

I'm looking for a way to detect when the user shakes their device to trigger a function in my react-native app. There's an "accelerator" sensor in react-native-sensors which I could probably use. Does anyone have experience with building such a thing? Any guidance would be appreciated.

https://react-native-sensors.github.io/docs/API.html

```
import { accelerometer } from "react-native-sensors";

const subscription = accelerometer.subscribe(({ x, y, z, timestamp }) =>
  console.log({ x, y, z, timestamp })
);
```

Comment: You could.  THe main problem is defining what a shake is-  is a sharp change in acceleration a shake?  Or do you want to look for shakes back and forth?  How long between shakes do you  want to wait before you call it a new shake?  And are how bad is it if you get a false positive and detect say the start of a car as a shake?  The simplest answer is just to look for big changes in the x, y, or z accelerations.  A complex answer could involve frequency analysis over a set of points.  What's your usecase?

Comment: A cool article on the different types of motions: https://medium.com/@aurelie.lebec/triggering-an-event-on-phone-movement-react-native-and-expo-32e55a4e184c

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options, checkout [react-native-shake](https://github.com/Doko-Demo-Doa/react-native-shake) for example.