# Is there a way to shake phone to call a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need some help not even sure if it is even possible but I'm looking at instead of an onPress on a button to just be able to shake the phone to call a function in react native?

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shake

BTW **This question is already answered** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890469/detecting-a-shake-device-event-with-react-native-sensors)
Please use the search button before asking a question

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google brought this up. Let me know how you get on. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shake